How do I seperate out two charts that share data?
I am trying to create a chart that shows the levelised cost of energy (LCOE) for nuclear power. My data source had data for two types of reactors -- large and small. Because of that, there are two LCOE values for every year, which creates this weird zigzag effect. I would like to make two horizontally concatenated charts -- one for each reactor type, with LCOE on the y-axis and year on the x-axis.
However, I can't figure out how to make one chart only look at the large reactor data and one chart only look at the small reactor data. I can successfully create two charts, but it just duplicates the original chart. What do I need to do to change that?
Here's my json:
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v5.json",
  "title": {
    "text": "Projected Cost of Nuclear Power",
    "subtitle": [
      "LCOE of Nuclear, $/MWh",
      "Source: NREL Annual Technology Baseline 2024"
    ],
    "color": "purple"
  },
  "data": {
    "url": "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Malcamo/Malcamo.github.io/refs/heads/main/Nuclear_LCOE_Cleaned.csv"
  },
  "background": "#d2ffd2",
  "hconcat": [
    {
      "view": {"fill": "white", "strokeOpacity": 0},
      "width": 300,
      "encoding": {
        "x": {"field": "Year", "type": "temporal", "title": null},
        "y": {"field": "LCOE", "type": "quantitative", "title": null},
        "color": {
          "scale": {"range": ["darkgreen", "teal", "darkblue"]},
          "condition": {
            "param": "hover",
            "field": "Scenario",
            "type": "nominal",
            "legend": null
          },
          "value": "grey"
        },
        "opacity": {"condition": {"param": "hover", "value": 1}, "value": 0.2}
      },
      "layer": [
        {
          "params": [
            {
              "name": "hover",
              "value": [{"Scenario": "Advanced"}],
              "select": {
                "type": "point",
                "fields": ["Scenario"],
                "on": "pointerover"
              }
            }
          ],
          "mark": {
            "type": "line",
            "strokeWidth": 8,
            "stroke": "transparent",
            "point": true
          }
        },
        {"mark": "line"},
        {
          "encoding": {
            "x": {"aggregate": "max", "field": "Year"},
            "y": {"aggregate": {"argmax": "LCOE"}, "field": "price"}
          },
          "layer": [
            {"mark": {"type": "circle"}},
            {
              "mark": {"type": "text", "align": "left", "dx": 4},
              "encoding": {"text": {"field": "Scenario", "type": "nominal"}}
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "view": {"fill": "white", "strokeOpacity": 0},
      "width": 300,
      "encoding": {
        "x": {"field": "Year", "type": "temporal", "title": null},
        "y": {"field": "LCOE", "type": "quantitative", "title": null},
        "color": {
          "scale": {"range": ["darkgreen", "teal", "darkblue"]},
          "condition": {
            "param": "hover",
            "field": "Scenario",
            "type": "nominal",
            "legend": null
          },
          "value": "grey"
        },
        "opacity": {"condition": {"param": "hover", "value": 1}, "value": 0.2}
      },
      "layer": [
        {
          "params": [
            {
              "name": "hover",
              "value": [{"Scenario": "Advanced"}],
              "select": {
                "type": "point",
                "fields": ["Scenario"],
                "on": "pointerover"
              }
            }
          ],
          "mark": {
            "type": "line",
            "strokeWidth": 8,
            "stroke": "transparent",
            "point": true
          }
        },
        {"mark": "line"},
        {
          "encoding": {
            "x": {"aggregate": "max", "field": "Year"},
            "y": {"aggregate": {"argmax": "LCOE"}, "field": "price"}
          },
          "layer": [
            {"mark": {"type": "circle"}},
            {
              "mark": {"type": "text", "align": "left", "dx": 4},
              "encoding": {"text": {"field": "Scenario", "type": "nominal"}}
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "config": {
    "legend": {
      "fillColor": "#ffffff",
      "strokeColor": "black",
      "padding": 5,
      "symbolType": "stroke"
    }
  }
}


Instead of concat, you want to facet or trellis your data by the column large/small. Have a read here to get you going: https://vega.github.io/vega-lite/docs/facet.html

I just did what davidebacci suggested, by faceting the data.
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v5.json",
  "title": {
    "text": "Projected Cost of Nuclear Power",
    "subtitle": [
      "LCOE of Nuclear, $/MWh",
      "Source: NREL Annual Technology Baseline 2024"
    ],
    "anchor": "middle",
    "color": "purple"
  },
  "data": {
    "url": "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Malcamo/Malcamo.github.io/refs/heads/main/Nuclear_LCOE_Cleaned.csv"
  },
  "background": "#d2ffd2",
  "facet":{"column": {"field":"Cleaned Reactor Size", "title":null}},
  "spec": {"view": {"fill": "white", "strokeOpacity": 0},
  "width": 300,
  
  "encoding": {
    "x": {"field": "Year", "type": "temporal", "title": null},
    "y": {"field": "LCOE", "type": "quantitative", "title": null},
    "color": {
      "scale": {"range": ["darkgreen", "teal", "darkblue"]},
      "condition": {
        "param": "hover",
        "field":"Scenario",
        "type":"nominal",
        "sort": ["Advanced", "Moderate", "Conservative"],
          "scale": {"range": ["darkgreen", "teal", "darkblue"]}
      },
      "value": "grey"
    },
    "opacity": {
      "condition": {
        "param": "hover",
        "value": 1
      },
      "value": 0.2
    }
  },
  "layer": [{
    "params": [{
      "name": "hover",
      "value": [{"Scenario": "Advanced"}],
      "select": {
        "type": "point",
        "fields": ["Scenario"],
        "on": "pointerover"
      }
    }],
    "mark": {"type": "line", "strokeWidth": 8, "stroke": "transparent", "point": true, "tooltip":true}
  }, {
    "mark": "line"
  }, {
    "encoding": {
      "x": {"aggregate": "max", "field": "Year"},
      "y": {"aggregate": {"argmax": "LCOE"}, "field": "price"}
    },
    "layer": [{
      "mark": {"type": "circle"}
    }, {
      "mark": {"type": "text", "align": "left", "dx": 4},
      "encoding": {"text": {"field":"Scenario", "type": "nominal"}}
    }]
  }],
  "config": {
    "legend": {
      "fillColor": "#ffffff",
      "strokeColor": "black",
      "padding": 5,
      "symbolType": "stroke"
    }
  }
}}

The relevant change is this bit here
"facet":{"column": {"field":"Cleaned Reactor Size", "title":null}},
"spec": {"view": {"fill": "white", "strokeOpacity": 0},


An alternative solution is to apply a filter Transform:
In each hconcat I simply add:
"transform": [{"filter": "datum['Cleaned Reactor Size'] === 'Large'"}],
or
"transform": [{"filter": "datum['Cleaned Reactor Size'] === 'Small'"}],

{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v5.json",
  "title": {
    "text": "Projected Cost of Nuclear Power",
    "subtitle": [
      "LCOE of Nuclear, $/MWh",
      "Source: NREL Annual Technology Baseline 2024"
    ],
    "color": "purple"
  },
  "data": {
    "url": "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Malcamo/Malcamo.github.io/refs/heads/main/Nuclear_LCOE_Cleaned.csv"
  },
  "background": "#d2ffd2",
  "hconcat": [
    {
      "title": "Cleaned Reactor Size: Large",
      "transform": [{"filter": "datum['Cleaned Reactor Size'] === 'Large'"}],
      "view": {"fill": "white", "strokeOpacity": 0},
      "width": 300,
      "encoding": {
        "x": {"field": "Year", "type": "temporal", "title": null},
        "y": {"field": "LCOE", "type": "quantitative", "title": null},
        "color": {
          "scale": {"range": ["darkgreen", "teal", "darkblue"]},
          "condition": {
            "param": "hover",
            "field": "Scenario",
            "type": "nominal",
            "legend": null
          },
          "value": "grey"
        },
        "opacity": {"condition": {"param": "hover", "value": 1}, "value": 0.2}
      },
      "layer": [
        {
          "params": [
            {
              "name": "hover",
              "value": [{"Scenario": "Advanced"}],
              "select": {
                "type": "point",
                "fields": ["Scenario"],
                "on": "pointerover"
              }
            }
          ],
          "mark": {
            "type": "line",
            "strokeWidth": 8,
            "stroke": "transparent",
            "point": true
          }
        },
        {"mark": "line"},
        {
          "encoding": {
            "x": {"aggregate": "max", "field": "Year"},
            "y": {"aggregate": {"argmax": "LCOE"}, "field": "price"}
          },
          "layer": [
            {"mark": {"type": "circle"}},
            {
              "mark": {"type": "text", "align": "left", "dx": 4},
              "encoding": {"text": {"field": "Scenario", "type": "nominal"}}
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "title": "Cleaned Reactor Size: Small",
      "transform": [{"filter": "datum['Cleaned Reactor Size'] === 'Small'"}],
      "view": {"fill": "white", "strokeOpacity": 0},
      "width": 300,
      "encoding": {
        "x": {"field": "Year", "type": "temporal", "title": null},
        "y": {"field": "LCOE", "type": "quantitative", "title": null},
        "color": {
          "scale": {"range": ["darkgreen", "teal", "darkblue"]},
          "condition": {
            "param": "hover",
            "field": "Scenario",
            "type": "nominal",
            "legend": null
          },
          "value": "grey"
        },
        "opacity": {"condition": {"param": "hover", "value": 1}, "value": 0.2}
      },
      "layer": [
        {
          "params": [
            {
              "name": "hover",
              "value": [{"Scenario": "Advanced"}],
              "select": {
                "type": "point",
                "fields": ["Scenario"],
                "on": "pointerover"
              }
            }
          ],
          "mark": {
            "type": "line",
            "strokeWidth": 8,
            "stroke": "transparent",
            "point": true
          }
        },
        {"mark": "line"},
        {
          "encoding": {
            "x": {"aggregate": "max", "field": "Year"},
            "y": {"aggregate": {"argmax": "LCOE"}, "field": "price"}
          },
          "layer": [
            {"mark": {"type": "circle"}},
            {
              "mark": {"type": "text", "align": "left", "dx": 4},
              "encoding": {"text": {"field": "Scenario", "type": "nominal"}}
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "config": {
    "legend": {
      "fillColor": "#ffffff",
      "strokeColor": "black",
      "padding": 5,
      "symbolType": "stroke"
    }
  }
}

